# How to know if CAFFE code is running using GPU or CUDA code?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I known that almost layer in CAFFE can run in CPU/GPU. In case of GPU, it has some mode, called engine. If `engine=CAFFE`, it will run with GPU and `engine=CUDNN`, it will run based on CUDA code. The default is DEFAULT mode

In my Makefile.config, I turn on CUDNN mode when build caffe

```
# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
USE_CUDNN := 1
```

In my prototxt, I have a layer, for example, Deconvolution layer

```
layer {
  name: "DeconvolutionLayer"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "DeconvolutionLayer"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    bias_term: false
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "msra"
    }    
  }
}
```

Note that, I did not set any value for `engine` flag. When I run, which mode will be use, GPU or CUDNN? The training script is

```
caffe/build/tools/caffe train --solver=solver.prototxt -gpu 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the `caffe.proto` it says `"The default for the engine is set by the ENGINE switch at compile-time."`. If you look into the `layer_factory.cpp` if `USE_CUDNN` is set then the default engine is set to `cuDNN`. So in your case it is CUDNN.